# How to pass query values from a ASP.NET page to a WPF page contained in an iframe?

Tags: asp.net, wpf, iframe

I have an ASP.NET web page that contains an iframe. In it I want to show a WPF page. When I load the page I do this:

```
string strPrint = ResolveClientUrl("~/FolderXXX/PageXXX.xbap?param1=value1&param2=value2");
printIfr.Attributes["src"] = strPrint;
```

The page loads perfectly, and shows my (few) controls, but I cannot access param1 and param2. I tried

```
NameValueCollection param = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString((ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.ActivationUri));
string letters = param["param1"];
```

but I get an empty string...

Comment: WPF is desktop technology. How are you going to show a WPF page in a web browser?

Comment: @Muad actually WPF was created to be "any target" technology... but even so, I'm actually not showing anything, I'm printing stuff, so "showing" data is not needed

Comment: you said "I want to show a WPF page" I can only go by what you write. sorry, failed that mind reading class back in university.

Comment: @Muad hahaha you are right, this time I didn't phrase my question well... In my defense, I must say it's only because I don't know what I'm doing! ;)

Comment: its OK, happens to all of us sometimes :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I was passing parameters properly, using the iframe src property and then from the WPF get those values using ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.ActivationUri

The problem with this seeming not to be working was that I'm using Visual Studio internal server. Switched to IIS and worked like a charm.

Hope this helps someone!